# Firewall status in resource monitor

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api, resource-monitor

In resource monitor under network, there is a tab called listening ports which has a column called firewall status. It has values like
1)allowed, not restricted
2)not allowed, not restricted
3)allowed, restricted

My understanding is that the first one represents whether the incoming traffic will be allowed or not.
(when I tested after disabling the firewall, everything changed to allowed)

My understanding of the second one is whether there is a rule restricting that connection or not. But in this case, allowed, restricted gives no sense because when it is restricted how can it be allowed.

And also there is an option to either block or allow all connections that do no match any available rules.
could anyone please explain these things in detail please?

Answer (score -1):

My understanding of Allowed/Restricted.
FW allows access to that port but with some restrictions.
For example, there is a rule in fw blocking access to that port for some IP addresses or allowing access from local subnet only.